# Identifying genuine phone number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, phone-number

I have a data set having a dedicated column for capturing phone numbers. My task is to validate the same since there are wrong entries like "9999999999","0123456789" and many others of similar nature.
I thought of tackling the issue by identifying the carrier names, so easily above instances can be ignored as there won't be any carrier names.
I came across a package called `phonenumbers`, and used the below code

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import carrier
ro_number = phonenumbers.parse("+91xxxxxxxxxx") # number is redacted purposely
carrier.name_for_number(ro_number, "en")
```

Which gave the output as `'BSNL MOBILE'`
I wanted to run this on the entire column of the dataframe, where a new column is created and against each number carrier name is recorded.

I tried to use `for` loop,

```
for i in df['phone_number']:
    ro_number = phonenumbers.parse(i)
    carrier.name_for_number(ro_number, "en")
```

But got the below error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-af01b9d8c9ef> in <module>
      1 for i in merged_Data['SELLER_NUMBER']:
----> 2     ro_number = phonenumbers.parse(i)
      3     carrier.name_for_number(ro_number, "en")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\phonenumbers\phonenumberutil.py in parse(number, region, keep_raw_input, numobj, _check_region)
   2834         raise NumberParseException(NumberParseException.NOT_A_NUMBER,
   2835                                    "The phone number supplied was None.")
-> 2836     elif len(number) > _MAX_INPUT_STRING_LENGTH:
   2837         raise NumberParseException(NumberParseException.TOO_LONG,
   2838                                    "The string supplied was too long to parse.")

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Not sure if that is the right way to go about to iterate over entire column.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `for i in df['phone_number'].tolist()`?

Comment: Hi @yudhiesh, that seems to have not solved the issue, getting the same error.

Comment: try for i in df['phone_number'].iteritems()

Comment: Hi @Lakpa, got this error ```AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find' ```, code i used ``` for i in merged_Data['SELLER_NUMBER'].iteritems():
    ro_number = phonenumbers.parse(i)
    carrier.name_for_number(ro_number, "en") ```

Comment: can you try: `df['phone_number'].apply(lambda x: carrier.name_for_number(phonenumbers.parse(x), 'en'))`?

Comment: Stackoverflow encourages providing the complete error message so responders can see which line of code caused the error and better understand the cause.

Comment: @Sid this error log should be placed in the question rather than comments as Stackoverflow recommends.  This way viewers of your questions don't have to read through all the comments to get all the information.

Comment: @DarrylG, I have updated the same.

Comment: @Sid do you know the data type of column 'phone_number' i.e. `df['phone_number'].dtype`?

Comment: @DarrylG data type is ``` dtype('int64') ```

Comment: @Sid int64 is a problem since the function **phonenumbers.parse** expects a string not a int.  Try converting the column to a string.

Comment: @Sid you can convert to string using `df['phone_number'] = df['phone_number'].apply(str)`

Comment: @DarrylG got below error ``` ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\phonenumbers\phonenumberutil.py in parse(number, region, keep_raw_input, numobj, _check_region)
   2841 
   2842     if not _is_viable_phone_number(national_number):
-> 2843         raise NumberParseException(NumberParseException.NOT_A_NUMBER,
   2844                                    "The string supplied did not seem to be a phone number.")
   2845 

NumberParseException: (1) The string supplied did not seem to be a phone number. ``` Is it suggested to think a different method to perform this exercise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236889/discussion-between-darrylg-and-sid).

Comment: @Sid Did you see the continue discussion link?

Comment: @DarrylG I have just responded over the link shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made two code mods:

1. Use method is_valid_number to check if number is with an exchange
2. Specify region (such as "US") since using None did not work for test case "18004444444" which is an MCI phone test number.

**Code**

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import carrier

def valid_number(number, region = "US"):
    ''' check validity of phone numbers (default to US region)
        
        Used default region as US since some numbers did not work using None
    '''
    # Parsing String to Phone number
    phone_number = phonenumbers.parse(number, region)
  
    # Validating a phone number (i.e. it's in an assigned exchange)
    return phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phone_number)
```

**Test With List**

```
data = ["+442083661177", "+123456789", "18004444444"]

for i in data:
    print(i, valid_number(i))

# Output
+442083661177 True
+123456789 False
18004444444 True    # note: this number doesn't work with default region = None
```

**Test With DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"phone_number": data})
df['valid'] = df['phone_number'].apply(valid_number)
# Resulting df
    phone_number    valid
0   +442083661177   True
1   +123456789  False
2   18004444444 True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

That error suggests that you're trying to call len() on an int. You should convert to a string first:

```
len(str(x))
```

Comment: Hi @wkilgo, same seems to have not solved the issue, getting the same error

Comment: What does df['phone_number'] contain? I'm guessing it's a dictionary containing phone number values? 

I'm trying to get a better understanding of your code so that I can understand the problem.